# Laptop Battery Showing Charging Icon Even Though It's Not Plugged In

Tags: battery, asus

(1) My laptop think it's charging even when it's not plugged in. (it shows the charging icon)

- Win 10 64 bit

(2) And also it does this weird thing when I shut it down, it's just restarting and I have to press the power button for 10-15 seconds for it turn off and the battery indicator is on even when it's completely turned off. (happened recently when I connect the battery)

(3)And the thing that confuses me is that I don't know which driver I should download for this laptop because in the back it has

- Asus model A42F
- MB ver K42F

Should I download A42F or K42F driver?

These 3 problems is confusing...
Thank you in advance for the help.

edit

- I've disconnect the battery and all the power source and press the power button for 30 seconds
- uninstalled the Microsoft ACPI driver
- the battery charge and discharge normally I still have 1.5 hours of usage.

Answer (score 0):

For 1 and 2, follow your manufacturer's documentation for doing a battery reset.

Vanilla battery reset:

1. Charge to Full.
2. Disconnect the AC.
3. Allow to discharge to zero.
4. Charge to 100%
5. Restart the computer.

This should reset the battery, and if still works as you describe, it may be time to replace.

For number 3, go to the manufacturer's support site for the Power Driver and update it. Also update the BIOS per the manufacturer's instructions.

Likely use the Asus model A42F identifier.

I answered in order but you should do step 3 (drivers) before resetting the battery (steps 1 and 2).

Comment: When I checked the Asus website the A42F and K42F have the exact same spec (Chipset, VGA, etc) but the K42F have better driver support. Do you think it's safe to install the K42F driver and bios?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Just follow the manufacturer's instructions for updating BIOS.