# Spilled water on mouse, now it shows battery level even when it's off

Tags: mouse, hardware-failure, battery, water-damage

As the title suggests, I spilled a little bit of water on my Logitech G900 mouse, and it works 100% fine, except that it's showing battery level even when I turn it off. It's only supposed to show that when it's plugged in to a charger. I know it's weird, I have never heard or found anything like that. I don't have a dissasembly kit at home, but if this suggests that there's a bigger hardware problem, I can get one and take it apart. Should I do so?

Comment: Unless you have a replacement for the PCB, what do you hope you achieve, from taking the mouse apart?

Comment: The very first thing you should have done was dismantle & clean it. Looks like you missed your chance. Take it to a professional & see if it can be rescued. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/392675/119271 which applies to mice as well as computers

Comment: Thank you!! When it happened I turned it off immediately (I think it was actually turned off before it was spilled on), and waited 4 hours. I also found a vanilla battery reset (https://superuser.com/questions/1618493/laptop-battery-showing-charging-icon-even-though-its-not-plugged-in), do you think it's okay to try it?

Comment: There are several good You Tube videos (search for "disassemble Logitech G900").   Take it apart for experience and see if you can in any way repair. I take lots of things apart.